# How to handle particular rectangular portion collision in AndEngine

Tags: android, collision-detection, andengine, collision

I am working on a boxing game using AndEngine. I have two animated sprites A and B, that represent the two boxers.  I want to differentiate between their healths.  If sprite A hits B by hand, B's health is reduced. How can I differentiate this sort of collision between two sprites?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is, when a boxer sprite has a collision with another boxer sprite, how do you determine which boxer should suffer the injury.  The basic answer is you need to collect and utilize more information than simply whether or not a collision occurred.  What I'd suggest is you think of the punches not as collisions between the entire sprite, but you calculate a shape that represents the fist and check it at the critical moment during the punch for collisions with the other boxer.  For example:

[image: punch]

When a boxer punches, you want to determine the critical period of time during the animation in which contact "matters" (at the full extension of the punch, presumably, and extending a little bit both before and after it.)  During that period of time, set some boolean on your boxer to true, and at other times, set it to false.  When it's true, in your boxer's update, you should calculate a shape that represents the "fist."  You don't have to render this shape (although it may be helpful to be able to do so for debugging and testing), you just need to calculate its location so that you can check the "fist" for collisions with the other boxer.  The fist impact area should be conceptually tied to the boxer doing the punch, so you're not checking for collisions between a boxer and his own fist.  You might want to have the impact shape as a field within the boxer entity.  So if the fist registers a collision during that time with another entity (i.e., the other boxer) apply some health damage to the other boxer.

You asked in the comment below for some additional implementation details.  The following code is not a complete implementation, but should get you started.

```
public class BoxerSprite extends AnimatedSprite {

    boolean     isPunching  = false;
    Rectangle   fist;

    public BoxerSprite(float pX, float pY, float pWidth, float pHeight, ITiledTextureRegion pTiledTextureRegion,
            ITiledSpriteVertexBufferObject pTiledSpriteVertexBufferObject) {
        super(pX, pY, pWidth, pHeight, pTiledTextureRegion, pTiledSpriteVertexBufferObject);

        //Create a "fist" object within your boxer sprite
        fist = new Rectangle(fistX, fistY, fistWidth, fistHeight, vertexBufferObjectManager);

        //Use setPosition to move the fist to the appropriate location during the animation.
        fist.setPosition(pX, pY);
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you for replay.how could i calculate fist portion of boxer.please explain to me clearly.